# how to return a quoted letters from spiltted list in Dart

Tags: dart

I tried to split a list into letters but the list comes into like this:

```
['a,b,c,d,e']
```

what i want is to get eacyh letter with quotation mark like this:

```
["a","b","c","d"]
```

what i tried is this:

```
void main() {
  printName("my school book");
}

void printName(String name){

final y =[name.split('')];
   y.shuffle();
   print('$y');
  
}
```

Comment: is my question clear?

Comment: No, your question are not clear. The code you have posted is not the one who have created your examples. Also, you have not specified the input you have. So I can only make a solution for you based on a lot of guesses on my part and therefore high risk of spending time on something that is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add quotation marks around each letter after the split, you can do something like this:

```dart
void main() {
  List<String> letters = [..."abcde".split('').map((letter) => '"$letter"')];
  print(letters); // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
}
```